# Windows Phone 7 - Is it possible to add additional key/values to push notifications messages

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

I'm testing out Windows Phone 7.5 push notifications. I have got the 3 different push types working fine (Toast, Tile and Raw) and am able to send messages from unit tests and a web application without any problems and receive them in my WP application. I want the ability to add extra properties to the push notification and the Raw push type does this perfectly for me and I can add custom key/value pairs or anything else to the push message and extract it on the phone app. I have just found out however that it only works if the application is running and my unit tests fail (suppressed notification status is received in unit test) when the phone application is not running (checked documentation which confirms this too). Is there anyway to add extra properties (key/values) to toast or tile messages or some way I can use raw in another way ? Toast notifications seem limited to a title property and an actual message property but I need to add additional data.

Just wondering if anyone had any suggestions / workarounds ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general practice I use is to initially send a raw notification to the device with phone-usable data embedded in the message. If my application is currently running then I can process the contents of the raw message and immediately make use of it on the phone. However if the application is not currently running on the phone you will receive notification from the push servers that the message could not be delievered. If I receive this response I send out a Toast / Tile notification.

With Toast notifications the only parametrisation you have access to is the URI that will launch the application. This is specified with the `wp:param` node of the message. Eg.

```
<wp:Notification xmlns:wp="WPNotification">
  <wp:Toast>
    <wp:Text1>Toast Title</wp:Text1>
    <wp:Text2>Toast sub title</wp:Text2>
    <wp:Param>/MainPage.xaml?LaunchedFrom=A%20Toast%20Notification</wp:Param>
  </wp:Toast>
</wp:Notification>
```

If the user taps on this toast notification your application will launch and navigate to `MainPage.xaml`. You can access the querystring passed in via the `NavigationContext.QueryString`.

Note: The `wp:Param` node can only be sent to Mango (and up) devices. Additionally the entire contents must be less than 256 characters or you'll receive a `PushErrorTypeMessageBadContent` error. (Thanks to Ritch Melton for pointing this out). More info available from the [Sending Push Notifications for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202945%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: Great addition! I wasn't aware of that. Is that the entire Uri or the querystring? Any chance of a link for that info?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202945(v=vs.92).aspx - Scroll down to the middle of the page in the 'Important Info' section. There's other constraints about load times and what not, so you have to be careful when trying to do too much with these notifications.

Comment: Thanks. Updated answer with relevant info.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I think I can add the extra data to the <wp:Param> as there are just a couple of extra bits of data I need and won't exceed 256 characters, hadn't thought of doing that. Otherwise for anything else bigger looks like I'll have to make a request back to the server to get it. Was hoping to avoid that if possible but thanks for the confirmation on this.

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, the [Microsoft Push Notification Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402558%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) is very strict in what types of messages you can send and receive. The intent of these push notifications is to provide simple push updates and not large amounts of data.  The flexible Raw type seems like it would fit the bill until you discover that:

> You can use a raw notification to send information to your application. If your application is not currently running, the raw notification is discarded on the Microsoft Push Notification Service and is not delivered to the device.

However, if you send a toast notification to your application, when the user clicks on the toast the application is started. When your application starts, you should check a service and retrieve the data you are trying to send from a web-service or other remote mechanism.